# One line for loop with check and raise exception in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

Is there a way to transform a code like:

```
total_size = 0
for file in files:
  if file.size > 1024:
    raise Exception("file too long")
  total_size = total_size + file.size
```

to

```
sum(file.size if file.size > 1024 else raise Exception("file too long") for file in files)
```

Comment: List-comprehensions or generator expressions should not have side-effects in the first place. Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: @PaulM. I am just asking

Comment: You could assert the file sizes first (using `any`), and then sum them (using `sum`), in two separate statements.

Comment: If you must, then I would factor out the check for file size into a small local function `has_valid_file_size` that raises the Exception.

I.e.: ```sum(file.size if is_valid_file_size(file.size) for file in files)``` and `is_valid_file_size` contains just the conditional that you had in the list comprehension.

Comment: using list comprehension, you can do the filtered summation, but, the exception raising can't be part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my current understanding of your question, I can suggest the following solution:

```py
class File:
    def __init__(self, name, size):
        self.size = size
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'File {} of size {} bytes'.format(self.name, self.size)

demoFiles = [File('a', 10), File('b', 20), File('c', 1100), File('d', 40), File('e', 50), File('f', 1200)]


# Your current code (corrected):
total_size = 0
for file in demoFiles:
    try:
        if file.size > 1024:
            raise Exception("file too long")
        total_size = total_size + file.size
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
print(total_size)

# Proposed shortened version
def mkExcp(aFile):
    try:
        if file.size > 1024:
            raise Exception("file too long")
        total_size = total_size + file.size
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        return 0

total_size = sum([file.size if file.size<=1024 else mkExcp(file) for file in demoFiles])
print(total_size)
```

Both the pieces of code, will produce the following output:

```bash
file too long
file too long
120
```

---

**Notes**:

1. I have created the File class for demonstration purpose only
2. The code you are using (*corrected version in my answer*) has following profiling

```bash
117 µs ± 2.64 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

3. The proposed code has following

```bash
126 µs ± 4.86 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

**What? List comprehension is slower?** - Yes, remember, list comprehension cannot do the exception handling for you, it has to call a function. This change of frame slows it down.

Comment: _bottom-line_: you should not use list-comprehension for this use-case, as @PaulM. has already mentioned in comments above.